# Cassandra Datastax OpsCenter "NO DATA" on some graphs

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I'm running on 1 node test cluster Cassandra Datastax OpsCenter 5.2.0, installed from Amazon Datastax AMI version 2.6.3 with Cassandra Community 2.2.0-1.

OpsCenter doesn't report any errors (All agents connected) yet on some graphs I see `NO DATA` (while I know that there been a lot of requests):

[image: NO DATA on Write Requests]

On some there is nothing:

[image]

some are working just fine, like OS: Load, Storage Capacity and OS: Disk Utilization.

What could be the reason for this? How to fix it?

---

### EDIT:

Opscenter logs seems to be fine. In `agent.log` file, I've found the following errors (dozens of times):

```
 ERROR [jmx-metrics-2] 2015-09-21 06:50:30,910 Error getting CF metrics
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:857)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:807)
    at opsagent.rollup$process_metric_map.invoke(rollup.clj:252)
    at opsagent.metrics.jmx$cf_metric_helper.invoke(jmx.clj:96)
    at opsagent.metrics.jmx$start_pool$fn__15320.invoke(jmx.clj:159)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR [jmx-metrics-4] 2015-09-21 06:50:38,524 Error getting general metrics
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentHashMap
    at clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom(RT.java:857)
    at clojure.lang.RT.nth(RT.java:807)
    at opsagent.rollup$process_metric_map.invoke(rollup.clj:252)
    at opsagent.metrics.jmx$generic_metric_helper.invoke(jmx.clj:73)
    at opsagent.metrics.jmx$start_pool$fn__15334$fn__15335.invoke(jmx.clj:171)
    at opsagent.metrics.jmx$start_pool$fn__15334.invoke(jmx.clj:170)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

BTW. In Datastax agent configuration file (`address.yaml`), I have only `stomp_interface` parameter set to my node IP.

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/philip-doctor/2b7c87f551a35a5c7c79

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't this case - I have all columns which this script tries to populate...

Comment: Can you show your agent logs and opscenterd log

Comment: Your agent is able to retrieve OS counters, so the error seems to be related with the agent not being able to connect to your cassandra node. I think this is likely a configuration issue in your agent's address.yaml. Please post the datastax-agent.log

Comment: I've included errors from agent.log file. I've also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777084/opsagent-unsupportedoperationexception-with-persistenthashmap . Any information which Datastax Agent versions are affected? Can I update Datastax agents from Opscenter? You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NO DATA` in this case was caused by bug in Datastax agent. I've included related error in my question. The same error is also mentioned here: [Opsagent UnsupportedOperationException with PersistentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777084/opsagent-unsupportedoperationexception-with-persistenthashmap)

After upgrading from Datastax Opscenter 5.2.0 to 5.2.1 and upgrading agent to the same version, problem went away.

Thank you @phact for our help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error before and it was due to a wrongly configured `address.yaml`.

In my case the issue was that I only wrote a simple IP address in the `hosts` setting and it was fixed by using an array syntax instead. It seemed that without that, the agent was using a wrong data type, which then issued an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Try to add your local interface IP (or whatever IP your cassandra node is listening on on your machine) to the `hosts` setting like so in `address.yaml`:

`hosts: ["<local-node-ip>"]`

Maybe also try adding the following settings to `address.yaml`, just to be sure that the correct parameters are used by the agent:

`rpc_address: <local-node-ip>`

`agent_rpc_interface: <local-node-ip>`